# CreateFile over network

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I have two programs that read and write to the same file.  One appends data, the other clears the file and then rewrites all data.

The two programs interact fine on the same computer but when I run one on another computer and open the file over my local network my append doesn't seem to get through in time.

My process is as follows:

Program 1:

- Open file with

  ```
  handle = CreateFile(str.c_str(),
           FILE_READ_DATA|FILE_APPEND_DATA,
           0,
           NULL,
           OPEN_ALWAYS,
           FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,
           NULL);
  ```
- Write data using:

  ```
  WriteFile(handle, line, strlen(line), &Written, NULL);
  ```
- Close file using:

  ```
  CloseHandle(handle);
  ```

Program 2:

- Open file with:

  ```
  handle = CreateFile(str.c_str(),
           FILE_READ_DATA|FILE_WRITE_DATA,
           0,
           NULL,
           OPEN_ALWAYS,
           FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,
           NULL);
  ```
- If file size is different than last time it was read using:

  ```
  size = GetFileSize(handle, &size_high);
  ```

  (I'm only looking at size here, size_high is ignored since file sizes are relatively small)) then close the file, open it using FILE_READ_DATA flag, reload data and then retry from previous step.
- Otherwise clear file data using:

  ```
  SetFilePointer(handle,0,NULL,FILE_BEGIN); 
  SetEndOfFile(handle);
  ```
- Rewrite all data using:

  ```
  WriteFile(handle, line, strlen(line), &Written, NULL);
  ```
- Close file using:

  ```
  CloseHandle(handle)
  ```

Program 1 prompts the user to retry the save if the file is locked by another program.
Program 2 retries a couple of times if the file is locked by another program.

It looks like when accessing the file over the network my append operation in program 1 is not being picked up by program 2 before it clears and rewrites its data.  I've tried opening the file in program 1 with FILE_FLAG_WRITE_THROUGH flag set and also using FlushFileBuffers(handle) before closing the file with no luck.

Is there something I'm missing in this process?

I am coding in Embarcadero C++ Studio if that helps.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: What's the underlying file system? If a network file system, I think it may related to its cache policy.

Comment: I think you need to synchronize the file I/O somehow since you are clearly having a race condition.

Comment: @Summer_More_More_Tea - this is the standard windows API file system isn't it?  I would have thought it's caching was handled the same if it's a local file or a network file.

Comment: @Alexey Frunze - I recognize it's a race condition but it seems to be inside the API calls.  Is there another way to synchronize outside of the API or some other API calls that I've missed?

Comment: I'm not sure it's a good solution to whatever you're trying to do. Why not use network for what it is, use sockets and exchange packets (using TCP or UDP or something else), maybe even some kind of highlevel application-level protocol?

Comment: @user2020342 Yes, you're right, standard windows API. But remind of the abstraction operating system provides you :)! The standard API hides implementation details of underlying system. Your underlying file system can be an NFS or NTFS, however, they share the interface, which is your windows API. As you said you may have problem synchronize these two processes. IMHO, two programs run on physically separated machines. In this case, lock is not efficient, since a lock can only be employed synchronizing `threads` in the same address space. You can try a file lock to sync these two `processes`.

Comment: @Summer_More_More_Tea - The API call locks the file when I open it so that my other program knows that the file is open in another program.  My problem is that when the other program opens a recently edited file and edits it, it seems to overwrite the previous edit before it has saved.

Comment: @Alexey Frunze - I'm not actually doing this only over a network, I've just found out that some users are using it this way and are having these issues.  Was just hoping there was an easy fix for it :P

Comment: File locks aren't robust for network shares. You need to use something else.

Comment: +1 for @DavidHeffernan - this file locking scheme will not work reliably on networked drives.  There is no quick fix that will insulate you from a pile of ongoing hassle with your customers :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

File locking is known not to work reliably and robustly for file access to network shares. Simply put, you need to find another mechanism to implement mutual exclusion. For example, use a client/server database design.

Comment: That's what I was afraid of but couldn't find an absolute statement like this.  Thank you very much for your answer